# Geo searching with Algolia

Tags: javascript, geolocation, algolia

I am implementing the geo search with algolia on the web.  My code is as below:

```
var searchClient = algoliasearch(Algol_APP_ID, Algol_API_KEY);
var itemIndex = searchClient.initIndex('item');

function searchItems(keyword, lat, lng) {
  var prom;
  var searchObj = {
    query: keyword,
    aroundRadius: 200
  };

searchObj.aroundLatLngViaIP = true;

return itemIndex.search(searchObj)
    .then(function (content) {
      console.log(content);
    return content;
  })
}
```

If I comment out `searchObj.aroundLatLngViaIP = true;`
 it gets items but once I include it, I get back nothing from algolia.  I think the problem is in the data, I do not have the the `_geoloc` parameter, which is in the tutorials, but I do not see anywhere in the documentation that, the `lat` and `lng` parameter must be encapsulated by that parameter.  However, if someone can confirm that, that is the issue, is there a way I can alias a paramter in algolia to that parameter rather than rewriting all the data in my DB to use that paramter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indeed using the `_geoloc` property is the only way to have geo localisation capabilities with Algolia. This is, today, not something configurable.

You don't have to rewrite the whole data in your DB, you could only rewrite the one in Algolia if you are able to do that in your production flow/data.